# Spring batch Itemwriter using Storedprocedure

Tags: spring-batch, jdbctemplate, tasklet

Can we use Stored procedure in Spring batch Itemwriter to write data or Tasklet is the only way?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking something like this
[Invoking Stored Procedure using Spring JdbcBatchItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066407/invoking-stored-procedure-using-spring-jdbcbatchitemwriter)

The answer is yes, implementing it is straightforward given the code below:

```
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    writer.setSql("CALL SP(:firstName, :lastName)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.That helped a lot.